# Does poltergeist/phantomjs have issues with remote scripts?

Tags: phantomjs, poltergeist

When I try to run Cucumber/poltergeist tests on my page, I get the following error:

```
Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

I'm loading my Javascript like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

What do I need to do to get phantomjs to load jQuery properly? Does phantomjs require you to host all scripts locally?

Comment: What's your phantomjs version? Do you see any errors?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any progress @wise_gremlin?

Comment: I'm having the same issue too. Did someone find the answer to this?